# eval.parent using incorrect environment

Tags: r, eval

In R, I noticed some odd behavior regarding `eval.parent` and the environment that it searches when evaluating variable names. The following is an example:

```
> f = function() {i = 1; g()}
> g = function() {eval.parent(substitute(i))}
> f()
[1] 1
```

This works as expected. The expression `i` is evaluated in the environment that called `g`, the body of `f`, and `1` is the result.

However, if I define `i` in the body of `g` as well, then that value is used instead despite the expression being evaluated in the parent frame.

```
> g = function() {i = 2; eval.parent(substitute(i))}
> f()
[1] 2
```

Why is the result `2` in this case? The definition of `i = 2` should be completely ignored by `eval.parent` because the expression is evaluated in the parent frame. Having examined the environments more closely, the call to `eval` by `eval.parent` is also passed the environment corresponding to the frame of `f` as checked by `sys.frames`.

Comment: Wrap substitute(i) in expression()

Comment: I think you have just demonstrated that `eval.parent()` gets evaluated _after_ `substitute` goes looking for `i`.